# R error argument 'findVar' is not an environment

Tags: r, excel, environment-variables, openxlsx

For working with excel files in R I use the openxlsx package. Works fine, as well for reading an xlsx-file into R as for writing to such a file from within R. Until today.
In one of my scripts I have this code:

```
library(openxlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = prog, tabColour = "limegreen")

#define styles
style.1 <- createStyle(fg = "#90EE90") #color even rows
style.2 <- createStyle(fg = "#DAF3EA") #color odd rows
style.1 <- createStyle(fg = "#90EE90")
```

to define a style to use for the output.
Since today this line gives an error as do al other lines in which I use createStyle. The error message is:

> Error in (function (env, objName)  : 
>     argument to 'findVar' is not an environment.

Can this be caused by updating R and Rstudio to the newest version? And more important: what can I do about this error?

```
Session info:  
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions.   /A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources /lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] bindrcpp_0.2        dplyr_0.7.4         data.table_1.10.4-3    openxlsx_4.0.17    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.3   magrittr_1.5     assertthat_0.2.0 R6_2.2.2             tools_3.4.3     
[6] glue_1.2.0       tibble_1.3.4     yaml_2.1.15      Rcpp_0.12.14         pkgconfig_2.0.1 
[11] rlang_0.1.4      bindr_0.1
```

Traceback gives the result below.

```
trace(back)
1: (function (env, objName) 
{
   obj <- get(objName, env)
   hasNullPtr <- .Call("rs_hasExternalPointer", obj, TRUE)
   if (hasNullPtr) {
       val <- "<Object with null pointer>"
       desc <- "An R object containing a null external pointer"
       size <- 0
       len <- 0
   }
   else {
       val <- "(unknown)"
       desc <- ""
       size <- object.size(obj)
       len <- length(obj)
   }
   class <- .rs.getSingleClass(obj)
   contents <- list()
   contents_deferred <- FALSE
   if (is.language(obj) || is.symbol(obj)) {
       val <- deparse(obj)
   }
   else if (!hasNullPtr) {
       if (size > 524288) {
           len_desc <- if (len > 1) 
               paste(len, " elements, ", sep = "")
           else ""
           if (is.data.frame(obj)) {
               val <- "NO_VALUE"
               desc <- .rs.valueDescription(obj)
           }
           else {
               val <- paste("Large ", class, " (", len_desc, 
                 capture.output(print(size, units = "auto")), 
                 ")", sep = "")
           }
           contents_deferred <- TRUE
       }
       else {
           val <- .rs.valueAsString(obj)
           desc <- .rs.valueDescription(obj)
           if (class == "data.table" || class == "ore.frame" || 
               class == "cast_df" || class == "xts" || class == 
               "DataFrame" || is.list(obj) || is.data.frame(obj) || 
               isS4(obj)) {
               contents <- .rs.valueContents(obj)
           }
       }
   }
   list(name = .rs.scalar(objName), type = .rs.scalar(class), 
       clazz = c(class(obj), typeof(obj)), is_data = .rs.scalar(is.data.frame(obj)), 
       value = .rs.scalar(val), description = .rs.scalar(desc), 
       size = .rs.scalar(size), length = .rs.scalar(len), contents = contents, 
       contents_deferred = .rs.scalar(contents_deferred))
  })(<environment>, "style.1")
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r). Show your `sessionInfo()` so we can see what versions of R and the package you are using. Maybe show the value of `traceback()` after you get the error.

Comment: I have added some extra lines of code and the session info

Comment: Problem solved.
First installed OS developer tools (https://www.cnet.com/how-to/install-command-line-developer-tools-in-os-x/), based on a tip elsewhere; didn't help.
After that I tried to run the command openxlsx::createStyle() in R (not R studio) and that worked fine. So removed Rstudio and installed it again. This did the job.

Comment: I have the same problem since updating to RStudio 1.1.414. Removing and reinstalling RStudio did not help.

Comment: Did you try to run the command in the R shell? And do you have the latest version of openxlsx (4.033)?